# How to hide or disable buttons?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my project I have two buttons called sign-in and sign-up button on my header.

What I want to achieve is,after successful sign-in i want to disable sign-in button and hide sign-up button.

Comment: Removed ionic from the title since it's properly tagged, improved some grammar and syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You could disable the sign-in button using ng-disabled (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and hide de sign-up button using ng-hide (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

Here an example: https://dynamicprogrammer.com/2014/05/16/a-few-different-ways-to-improve-user-feedback-in-our-ionic-application-part-6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use to *ngIf="isLoggedIn" to hide any component